# How to test Silverlight application with Webdriver using Java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, silverlight-4.0

How to test Silverlight application with Webdriver using Java?

Is there an way to automate the Silverlight app with Selenium Webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

There is also a ruby based open source tool;

http://www.natontesting.com/2010/07/20/announcing-bewildr-test-your-wpf-ui-apps-with-ironruby/

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend Sikuli. https://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/

Writing it in Java, the feel is similar to Selenium. But it's based on images. Crop out an image of thing you want to click on. Sikuli locates it by taking a screenshot of the whole page and looks for a match.